# offset and margin on bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with offset and margins on bootstrap 4, i want to achieve
 something like this picture everything is working except white spaces between boxes, when you go to medium size there is blue and yellow box next to each other but when i put mr-md-2 then blue box goes down, why ? i want white spaces between all boxes and sizes like in picture [image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

  <style>

  </style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row grid " >
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 mr-md-2 col-lg-3 offset-lg-3 "  style="background-color:burlywood; height:200px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 ml-md-2 col-lg-3 "  style="background-color:orange; height:200px;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row grid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mt-md-2 mt-md-3 col-md-4 col-lg-6 " style="background-color:black;height:200px; "></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 mt-md-2 offset-md-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-3 " style="height:200px;background-color:red; "></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row grid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 mt-md-2 offset-md-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-0 "  style="background-color:yellow;height:200px; "></div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 mt-md-2 mr- col-lg-3 mr-lg-0 offset-lg-6 " style="background-color:blue; height:200px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no more `col-xs` in the bootstrap ... better read the doc of V4 and follow it, it seems you are following the old version

Comment: yeah i forgot to edit that, but it doesnt change it, it will still work, but how to apply white spaces like picture above ?

Comment: read the doc and how flexbox is used ... there is better alternative than the classic offset classes, Better rely on alignment. in you screen it's clear that you need to use center, space between, flex-end, flex-start, etc

Answer (score 0):

Consider that in the BS Grid system there are no margins between `col`umns (or between `row`s for that matter) but there are gutters:

Run this snippet in a full screen and resize your window:

```css
.row > div {
  /* background-color: lightsteelblue; */
  margin-top:20px;
}

.content {
  background-color: burlywood;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-3">
      <div class="content">r1c1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="content">r1c2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
      <div class="content">r2c1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 offset-md-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-3 ">
      <div class="content">r2c2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 offset-md-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-0 ">
      <div class="content">r3c1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-6">
      <div class="content">r3c2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```